# Determine the conditional probability and uniform distribution of a random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, conditional-probability

> Given that $X$ is a random variable, such that
> $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=\frac{1}{4}, P(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$, determine: (a) the
> uniform distribution of $X^2$ and (b) the conditional
> probabilities of $X$ given $X^2$.

I am not sure how to go about doing these.

For (a), I think that $X^2(\omega) = \{0,1\}$ but then what do I do with the probabilities? Do I simply square them as well?

For (b), I know that: $P(X=x \ | \ X^2 = x^2) = \frac{P(X=x, X^2 = x^2)}{P(X^2 = x^2)}$. But then how do I go on from here?

Comment: Note that $P(X^2=1)=P(X=-1)+P(X=+1)$

Comment: Could you explain why we would do that? What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: You don't square probabilities (as you asked in OP). Regarding Henry's hint: do you see that $\{X=-1\}\cup\{X=+1\}$ is a disjoint union giving $\{X^2=1\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,
$
\{X^2=1\}= \{X=-1\}\cup\{X=1\},
$
so
$$
\mathbb P(X^2=1) = \mathbb P(X=-1)+\mathbb P(X=1) = \frac12.
$$Moreover $\{X^2=0\}=\{X=0\}$ so,
$$
\mathbb P(X^2=0)=\mathbb P(X=0)=\frac12.
$$
For the conditional distribution, we use the definition of conditional probability:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=0\mid X^2=0) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=0,X^2=0)}{\mathbb P(X^2=0)}=\frac{\mathbb P(X^2=0)}{\mathbb P(X^2=0)} = 1\\
\mathbb P(X=1\mid X^2=1) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=1,X^2=1)}{\mathbb P(X^2=1)}
=\frac{\mathbb P(X=1)}{\mathbb P(X^2=1)} = \frac{1/4}{1/2}= \frac12\\
\mathbb P(X=-1\mid X^2=1) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=-1,X^2=1)}{\mathbb P(X^2=1)}
=\frac{\mathbb P(X=-1)}{\mathbb P(X^2=1)} =\frac{1/4}{1/2}= \frac12.
\end{align}

Comment: I understand everything you wrote, except for: $\mathbb P(X^2=1) = \mathbb P(X=-1)+\mathbb P(X=1) = \frac12$. Where does this come from?